# undo: sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove

Tags: settings, cpufreq, tlp

As the question says, I issued `sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove` cause that's what an article on configuring **TLP** says... but after doing the "configurations" my graphics went back to crap. So I uninstalled **TLP** re-installed my Graphics drivers, but I don't know how to undo the step described in the title of this question.

I read about **update-rc.d** and I issued `sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand defaults`

```
mymachine@deus:~$ sudo update-rc.d ondemand defaults
[sudo] password for mymachine: 
update-rc.d: warning: ondemand stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match LSB Default-Stop values (none)
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/ondemand ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
   /etc/rc1.d/K20ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
   /etc/rc6.d/K20ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
   /etc/rc2.d/S20ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
   /etc/rc3.d/S20ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
   /etc/rc4.d/S20ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
   /etc/rc5.d/S20ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
```

But I'm not sure if that fixed it, because I don't really know what I'm trying to fix (put back to how it was)

Help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove` you removed the symlinks of this daemon. So the daemon is no longer executed while switching to the configured runlevel (or at bootup).

I looked at my machine what's the default configuration of this service:

```
user@host:~# find /etc/rc* -name "*ondemand*"
/etc/rc2.d/S99ondemand
/etc/rc3.d/S99ondemand
/etc/rc4.d/S99ondemand
/etc/rc5.d/S99ondemand
```

So, we see the daemon starts in runlevels 2, 3, 4 and 5 with start number 99. To set that back to this configuration type:

```
user@host:~# update-rc.d ondemand start 99 2 3 4 5 .
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/ondemand ...
   /etc/rc2.d/S99ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
   /etc/rc3.d/S99ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
   /etc/rc4.d/S99ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
   /etc/rc5.d/S99ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
```

**Edit**

According to the script `/etc/init.d/ondemand` the script sets every cpu governor to `ondemand` for every cpu that supports this setting.

- A (scaling-)governor manages how the cpufrequency is adjusted automatically.
- `ondemand` means that the frequency is adjusted to the current needs. The frequency can so change rapidly up or down.

You can find out which governors are available for your cpus by:

```
user@host:~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
userspace powersave conservative ondemand performance
userspace powersave conservative ondemand performance
userspace powersave conservative ondemand performance
userspace powersave conservative ondemand performance
```

So yes it's the same configuration for all machines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it the same configuration for all machines? I mean doesn't the system's CPU matter?

Comment: @Deus Deceit: see my edit